# How would I go about condensing html tags?

Tags: html

I want to condense several html tags into one or just a selection. For example I could turn this:

```
<html>
<body>
```

Into This:

```
<mytag>
```

I just want a clean neat way of using multiple tags at once. Classes would be fine too in fact div classes or something along the lines of that would be good. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: That's not how HTML works. Sorry if it gets too messy and bloated for you, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define custom tags for HTML, but you can omit some closing tags and even a couple of opening ones. See http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-html.html or directly the specs http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html .

Note that this is allowed **only** for HTML and not for XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

With html only this will be hard to realize. You could however do something in PHP, using a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), where you replace {mytag} with `<html><body>`.

But by using a template engine, you might as well eliminate the problem you seem to have, 'cause to me it isn't completely clear why you would want something like this.